# Weakly unconditionally Cauchy series in $X^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weakly-cauchy-sequences

Let $X$ be a Banach space. A series $\sum x_n$ in $X$ is *weakly unconditionally Cauchy (or weakly uncontionally convergent)* if $\sum |x^*(x_n)| < +\infty$ for every $x^* \in X^*$.

Exercise 3, page 114 of Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces* reads:

> The bounded linear operators from a Banach space $X$ into $\ell_1$
> correspond precisely to the sequences $(x_n^*)$ in $X^*$ for which
> $\sum |x^*_n(x)| < +\infty$, for each $x \in X$, i. e., **the weakly
> unconditionally Cauchy series in $X^*$.**

I'm having trouble with the bolded part. More precisely, I don't see why $\sum |x^*_n(x)| < +\infty$ for each $x \in X$ implies that $\sum x^*_n$ is weakly unconditionally Cauchy in $X^*$ (that is, $\sum |x^{**} (x^*_n)| < +\infty$ for every $x^{**} \in X^{**}$).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I may be off here, but: a given $(x_n^*)$ defines a bounded operator taking $x$ to $( x_n^*x)$. Proving the other direction for the adjoint of this particular operator restricted to $c_0$ (use exercise 2) shows $(x_n^*)$ is in fact WuC.

Comment: That settles it! Thanks a lot.